# Apache Zeppelin: get built in table data in code

Tags: angularjs, apache-zeppelin

Apache Zeppelin 0.8.0 allow to modify data in cells in built-in table.

I assume new values are linked to some variable inside angular scope.

How can I find out what is the name of this variable, so I'd be able to read it in the next paragraph using zeppelin context:

`z.angular("tableData??")`

Is it possible to get all variables available in zeppelin context?

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for now I've found an indirect way of doing it. It's a bit tacky way, so I'm still looking for better solution.

In the example below I'm implementing simplified scenario, where I just need to remove selected lines.

There are few features I'm using:

1. Table grid allow to incorporate html into the cells. 

   `%spark.sql
   select product, price, '%html <input class="input_data" ... />' from table_a`

   Unfortunately it's impossible to use `%angular` inside table, so I've requested this feature: [ZEPPELIN-3068](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-3068)
   Using this feature we can add another column into the table with any html element (checkbox, input field or external link). I can use selected variables from table to generate unique ids.
   It can even be a small form with POST request to web-service that will immediately perform requested changes.
2. Next paragraph will contain javascript that read data from html elements we've created above and store it in zeppelin context.

   %angular

   document.getElementsByClassName("input_data")

ps. if anyone need code, I can add full script.